# Changed GUID - Now uninstall not working

Tags: wix

Having a major problem. I read that Rob M said to use `Guid="*"` whenever possible so I changed all of my Guid's to this. Uninstalling my product is messing up now though. The files are successfully removed but the shortcuts, services and registry are not. Please Help

This is my service:

```
  <Component Id="service" Guid="*">
    <File Id="service.exe" Name="service.exe" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.Bin)\service.exe"/>
    <ServiceInstall Id="service.exe" Name="[PRODUCTNAME]" Description="[ProductName]" Account="[SERVICEACCOUNT]" Password="[SERVICEPASSWORD]" Arguments=" /start [ProductName]" Start="auto" Interactive="yes" Type="ownProcess" Vital="yes" ErrorControl="critical" />
    <ServiceControl Id="service.exe" Name="[PRODUCTNAME]" Stop="both" Start="install" Remove="uninstall" Wait="no"/>
  </Component>
```

This is the uninstall log:

```
Service '' () could not be stopped. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to stop system services.

MSI (s) (DC:D0) [14:25:02:018]: Executing op:  ActionStart(Name=DeleteServices,Description=
Deleting services
,Template=
Service: [1]
  )
  MSI (s) (DC:D0) [14:25:02:018]: Executing op:     ProgressTotal(Total=2,Type=1,ByteEquivalent=1300000)
MSI (s) (DC:D0) [14:25:02:018]: Executing op: ServiceControl(,,Action=8,Wait=0,)
MSI (s) (DC:D0) [14:25:32:064]: Executing op: ServiceControl(,Name=OPC,Action=8,Wait=0,)


Info 1922.

Service '' () could not be deleted. Verify that you have sufficient privileges to remove system services.
```

Its not picking up the name, anyone know why it would do this?

Comment: Is this on a product you made? Or did you make changes to someone else's program you installed?

Comment: @ObsessiveSSOℲ This is my own product that I am creating an installer for.

Comment: OK. I honestly don't know but this info can keep this question from being downvoted/closed/etc if you edit ias much info as you can into the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How is your property "PRODUCTNAME" defined? If it's not a constant, please verify that it's initialization is performed during uninstall sequence

Comment: Additionally as I know, [ProductName] and [PRODUCTNAME] are different properties: first one is private and second is public. Is it supposed in your installer to use them both? As for me it looks confusing

Comment: Hi, `[PRODUCTNAME]` is set via a custom Action which is set to run for both install and uninstall but I will explicitly set it for uninstall and see if that makes a different. Thanks

Comment: Please view the verbose log and find if this custom action was really executed before your error occurs. Maybe you scheduled this custom action too late for uninstall phase. Could you add this custom action declaration to the question?

Comment: I found my problem, I had the custom action setting the `[PRODUCTNAME]` only in the `InstallUISequence` which is not evaluated on uninstall, placing the custom action in `InstallExecuteSequence` solved this. Thank you..:)

Answer (score 3):

First questions first:

- Have you already released a version of this product? If so, changing component GUIDs is likely a huge violation of component rules, so you should not change these once released. If it's only been on your test machine, that's not important.
- Are you resetting your test machine such that the violation of component rules is not affecting the uninstall, or are you attempting to perform some sort of upgrade before this failing uninstallation?
- What does the verbose MSI log from uninstallation indicate?

Comment: No it has not been released yet. How do I reset my machine as you say in question two? I will run a verbose log now and paste the relevant parts.

Comment: Typically to reset the test machine you should use the revert functionality of your virtual machine host. What's that, you're not using a VM? Start doing so. As otherwise you have to resort to tools like MSIZAP (which only deletes records, not real data) or even reinstalling Windows if you want a truly clean environment.

Answer (score 0):

[MSIZAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370523%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), will be the ultimate way to eliminate everything installed on the machine by the installer.  I do recommend that you test it on a Proof of concept of what you are trying to do, and use a VM for all installing tests.